# Usage Limit for Inviting a Large Google Group on Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I’ve got a friend who runs a pretty big networking event (1000+ attendees). And he wants to send everyone a Google Cal invite. I’m aware of the 200 person direct invite limit. However Google’s own docs say to create a Google Group and invite that group.

So he did that. But now he’s getting the following error:

The event couldn't be updated. You might have reached a calendar use limit

Any idea what could be going on? Or what other simple alternatives could be?

Answer (score 0):

There are different steps that reach that single error. Without knowing the step by step it is only possible to guess what actions triggered that error. Nevertheless you can easily pinpoint which operation is the inadequate one by checking the following guidelines.

Familiarize yourself on [how to avoid Calendar use limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en). In particular you want to identify your friends account to see if it is limited or not. Then you can test the different approaches if a limit is hit. Additionally if you know which steps took your friend, then you can pinpoint exactly which limit was reached, and therefore you only have to wait the time to replenish. Feel free to drop a comment if you have information for a more in depth answer.